# Netplan not updating vlan

Tags: networking, netplan

I have configured multiple Vlan under a single interface. For operations need we have to change two Vlan, so i have just changed the Vlan id and name only other all information like IP address, route all are unchanged. After applying the configuration now i am seeing four Vlan. Two old vlan and two new vlan.

N.B. I have just changed the Vlan ID 244,242 with 254,252

[ifconfig output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbtGb.jpg)
[netplan config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfYEu.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

When you remove an interface completely from your netplan config, netplan (or specifically, networkd) can no longer distinguish between a removed config and an interface that you have manually configured outside of netplan.  You can remove the no-longer-used vlans manually at runtime from the command line after applying the netplan config, or you can reboot the system to get a clean network state.

Comment: Can you please help at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1201815/vlan-over-netplan-in-18-04-lts/1201864?noredirect=1#comment2016401_1201864

Comment: Dear @slangasek, Thank you very much for your answer. I have resolved the issue by restarting the server. But i would like to know how can i remove unused vlan manually at runtime.

Comment: @MasudRana You need to run a command like `ip address delete dev en0.999` as shown at http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/ip-address.8.html . Unfortunately, you cannot do this *and* activate interfaces via `netplan` at the same time, so you may get locked out of the node one way or another.

Comment: I found that `ip address delete dev en0.999` gave back `RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported` Using `ip link delete en0.999` worked for me.